# What is timeline_like_chaining in the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Here is part of the json I get back:

```
    "value": {
        "page_suggestions_on_liking": 2,
        "engagement_pyml": 44,
        "page_browser": 30,
        "outbound_click_chaining": 18,
        "feed_story": 11,
        "mobile_page_browser": 56,
        "wap": 1,
        "comment_chaining": 71,
        "mobile": 25,
        "page_finch_related_pages": 1,
        "feed_pyml": 121,
        "page_timeline": 2,
        "search": 5,
        "page_profile": 24,
        "pagelike_adder_for_reactivated_users": 18,
        "timeline_collection": 6,
        "launch_point_home_pyml": 5,
        "sponsored_story": 2,
        "feed_chaining": 57,
        "mobile_page_suggestions_on_liking": 8,
        "timeline_like_chaining": 135,
        "api": 14,
        "all_category_pyml": 38,
        "launch_point_discover_pyml": 13
      },
```

What is timeline_like_chaining and how is it different from feed_chaining?

Answer (score 0):

The "timeline_like_chaining" metric refers to a user liking your page when your page was suggested after they liked a similar page. (source: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1504548336228785/)

"feed_chaining" - People who liked your Page after Facebook automatically suggested a story about a friend liking your page.(source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights)